# ¿Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR a SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, regex

Quiero convertir lo siguiente a *MS SQL Server*:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.DESCRIPTION,'CATEGORY=([^,]*)(,|\Z)',1,1,'c',1)
```

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo de cómo funciona utilizando Oracle y/o explicar el código que tienes?

Comment: Que yo sepa, SQL Server no tiene una funcion como `regexp_substr`. Creo que vas a tener que definir la logica "manualmente", o sea usando `charindex()` y `substring()`, sin regex.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sin regex (y sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas)

Para seleccionar el texto entre `CATEGORY=` y la primer `,` que le sigue (o hasta el final del texto):

```sql
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(m.DESCRIPTION,
                         CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION) + LEN('CATEGORY='),
                         CHARINDEX(',',m.DESCRIPTION+',',CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION)+1) - CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION) - LEN('CATEGORY=')
                        )
     ELSE ''
END
```

Ejemplo:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
|    |                  DESCRIPTION                  |  Resultado  |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=ABC,OTRO=####              | ABC         |
|  2 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=ABCDEF,OTRO=####,MAS=GHIJK | ABCDEF      |
|  3 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=A B C D E F,OTRO=####      | A B C D E F |
|  4 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=,OTRO=####                 |             |
|  5 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=ABC                        | ABC         |
|  6 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=ABCDEF                     | ABCDEF      |
|  7 | ID=123444,CATEGORY=                           |             |
|  8 | CATEGORY=ABC,OTRO=####                        | ABC         |
|  9 | CATEGORY=                                     |             |
| 10 | ID=123444,OTRO=####                           |             |
| 11 | ABCDEF                                        |             |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

[<kbd>Ejemplo en rextester.com</kbd>](http://rextester.com/VVIKYI21002)

---

#### Que sólo coincida con el texto en mayúsculas

Si además se quiere que sólo coincida con el texto respetando mayúsculas y minúsculas, depende de qué intercalación (*COLLATION*) se esté utilizando en la base de datos.

- El "CS" al final significa que diferencia mayúsculas de minúsculas (*Case Sensitive*), al contrario de "CI" (*Case Insensitive*).

Alternativamente, se puede cambiar sólo para una consulta usando [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184391.aspx), como por ejemplo `Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

- Se puede usar cualquier otra siempre y cuando se use la variante "CS", o en su defecto "bin".

Sentencia:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(m.DESCRIPTION,
                         CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) + LEN('CATEGORY='),
                         CHARINDEX(',',m.DESCRIPTION+',',CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)+1)
                            - CHARINDEX('CATEGORY=',m.DESCRIPTION COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) 
                            - LEN('CATEGORY=')
                        )
     ELSE ''
END
```

[<kbd>Ejemplo en rextester.com</kbd>](http://rextester.com/KFQ62789)

---

#### Para usar regex

Si, en cambio, estás buscando usar expresiones más complejas, para poder usar regex en SQL Server, deberías emplear una función definida por el usuario con [integración CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx) (*Common Language Runtime*).

El siguiente artículo muestra cómo usar la integración CLR:

- [Usando Integración CLR en SQL Server 2005](http://albertomorillosqlserver.blogspot.com.ar/2011/04/usando-integracion-clr-en-sql-server.html)

Y el siguiente artículo muestra un ejemplo para integrar regex en SQL Server:

- [*Working with Regular Expressions*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2005/06/29/working-with-regular-expressions/)

Comment: Que paciencia has tenido para traducirlo. Probablemente lo unico que faltaria seria forzar un `collate` para corresponder al parametro `'c'` de Oracle. En la version de Oracle, `CaTeGoRy=ABC` no retornaría nada.

Comment: @sstan Buen punto. Pasé por alto la `'c'`. Lo incorporé en la última edición.